# parsing html through get_file_contents()

Tags: php, parsing, dom, screen-scraping

is have been told that the best way to parse html is through DOM like this:

```
<?

$html = "<span>Text</span>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $html);

$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("span");
foreach( $elements as $el)
{
    echo $el->nodeValue . "\n";
}


?>
```

but in the above the variable $html can't be a url, or can it??
wouldnt i have to use to function get_file_contents() to get the html of a page?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile](http://php.net/domdocument.loadhtmlfile) to load HTML from an URL.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($path);
```

`DOMDocument::loadHTML` parses a string of HTML.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($path));
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be, but it depends on allow_url_fopen being enabled in your PHP install. Basically all of the PHP file-based functions can accept a URL as a source (or destination). Whether such a URL makes sense is up to what you're trying to do.

e.g. doing `file_put_contents('http://google.com')` is not going to work, as you'd be attempting to do an HTTP upload to google, and they're not going allow you to replace their homepage...

but doing `$dom->loadHTML('http://google.com');` would work, and would suck in google's homepage into DOM for processing.

Comment: okay, i replaced $html with a url but its still not feeding back the tags?

Comment: PHP DOM is quite picky about html syntax, and even slightly malformed HTML will cause it to choke.  Might want to turn on error/warning display and see if anything shows up when you load the remote document.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble using DOM, you could use `CURL` to parse. For example:

```
$url = "http://www.davesdaily.com/";

$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$input = curl_exec($curl);

$regexp = "<span class=comment>([^<]*)<\/span>";
if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
  foreach($matches as $match);
}
  echo $match[0];
```

The script should grab the text between `<span class=comment>` and `</span>` and store inside an array `$match`. This should echo `Entertainment`.